# Pdf client side signing via ITextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to simulate client side signing via iTextSharp.

I have valid certificate, which were exported in 2 files - .cer file (public key) and .pfx file (with private key), pfx file is used as keystore. Public key used on "server".

Also I have a pdf file - for example https://yadi.sk/i/6vuDlEPXi7oYz. My code copied in this gist: https://gist.github.com/alex-t0/f446ccb5ca5e8936b778.

In a nutshell, there are 3 methods:

- ServerSidePrepare (prepare hashes, public key used)
- ClientSideSign (signing via private key)
- SaveSignedDocumentOnServer (combining signature into pdf on server).

But this code generates pdf document, which signature is not valid. When used method MakeSignature.SignDetached signature in pdf is valid, all ok.

How to debug this and find problem? Or may be other examples of pdf client side signing? With server part, in c#.

Comment: Can you share a sample result PDF

Comment: Of course: wrong file when client signing used: https://yadi.sk/i/NAyqu9dii88ra. Correct file when MakeSignature.SignDetached used: https://yadi.sk/i/LKJOdhOfi88wb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the wrong digest in your `GetEncodedPKCS7` call.

When first building the authenticated attributes you (correctly) use

```
sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(messageHash, now, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS)
```

but later when actually building the PKCS7 signature container you do

```
result.Sign.GetEncodedPKCS7(result.Hash, result.Now, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

The parameters of these two calls must be identical (with the exception of the additional `ITSAClient` argument in the latter call). Otherwise the final authenticated attributes (built in `GetEncodedPKCS7`) are different from the original ones (built in `getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes`) and would require a different signature value.

Thus, you should include the `byte[] messageHash` in your DTO and use it in `SaveSignedDocumentOnServer`.

Comment: Great! I update my gist, may be it will be useful for somebody.